# Arrow-implication

Tags: symbols, arrows, logic

I'm writing my thesis and I need use a symbol of science implication that looks like

[image]

or maybe something like

[image: right fish tail]

but thicker.

I'm curious how to generate it.

This link 
[How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)
doesn't help me

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean `$\rightarrow$`, i.e. →  or  `$\Rightarrow$`, i.e. ⇒ ?

Comment: `\to` is a shorthand for `\rightarrow`.

Comment: It's just simply implication, I need it with hooked tail

Comment: @Saizou: See [Comprehensive Symbol Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) please for an extensive collection of arrow commands. The tables therein from numbers 137 to 164 all deal with arrows

Comment: I can't see the arrow there

Comment: @Saizou The drawing is too imprecise to give a clue, sorry. Can you improve it?

Comment: Is it something like in [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cz5R.png)?

Comment: @egreg yes it is but it should be thicker

Comment: Aries rotated 90 degrees is close: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Astro_signs.svg/2000px-Astro_signs.svg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First option (with STIX)

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows3}{LS2}{stixtt}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\saizouimplies}{\mathrel}{arrows3}{'053}

\begin{document}

$A\saizouimplies B \rightarrow C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second option (with NewTX)

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{ntxsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\saizouimplies}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{74}

\begin{document}

$A\saizouimplies B \rightarrow C$

\end{document}
```

[image]